# Wildfly-Swarm Jax-RS Client

Tags: rest, client, jax-rs, wildfly-swarm

I have a Wildfly-Swarm server running, but it needs to send a request to another rest-server.
I tried using JAX-RS-Client, but failed.

The Code-Snipped executing the Request is

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Invocation.Builder request = client.target(automatonUri)
    .path("/self/isAlive")
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
boolean isAlive = request.get(Boolean.class);
```

When running this, I always get the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder` Exception.

I'm using the following fractions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I tried adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-client-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But then I just get `com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present` when running any junit test.

Any idea? Or any example I could look at?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add an explicit dependency on RESTEasy Client, something like

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.jboss.resteasy}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Works as intended. I even had it in there but it broke the whole REST-Endpoint. I didn't realize I should have set it to provided. Thanks a lot